# Alterar dados da coluna

Tags: c#, sql-server, query

Como posso alterar os dados da coluna? Queria alterar alguns bits para false mas não sei como.

```
        using (SqlCommand cmdadd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Usuarios (Cadastro) VALUES (@Cadastro)", connection2))
    {
cmdadd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Cadastro", false));
    }
```

Porém não queria adicionar, queria alterar, como ficaria o código?

Comment: https://www.devmedia.com.br/comandos-basicos-em-sql-insert-update-delete-e-select/37170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de insert use o comando Update, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
"UPDATE [Nome da Tabela SET [Nome do campo] = [Expressão] WHERE Cadastro = false"
```

Assim o sql vai sobrepor os valores do campo com os valores do SET e apenas no campo onde o Cadastro for False, se não usar um Where você pode acabar editando
todos da tabela, o que certamente iria ser inconveniente para você, se a explicação não foi clara, visite a fonte.

Fonte: https://sqlcomoumtodo.wordpress.com/category/update/

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlCommand cmdadd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Usuario set Cadastro = @Cadastro where xxx = @yyy", connection2))
{
    cmdadd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Cadastro", false));
    cmdadd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@yyy", false));
}
```

A coluna **xxx** seria uma coluna de um identificador único da sua tabela.

não esqueça de enviar o parâmetro para fazer update.. pq update sem where é complicado :P